GraphQL to query Wordpress page by URI and language
I'm running Wordpress with Polylang for i18n headless with GraphQL and Astro and I would like to query Wordpress for a page by URI and language.
What I've come up with is to be able to query a page by it's language and by ID like so:
query MyQuery6 {
  pages(where: {language: EN, id: 102}) {
    edges {
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}

This will give me the title of the page with ID 102 which is great. But since ID is a little bit iffy I would like to query for a post URI instead. But I can't seem to figure out how that query would look like? Or could I do two queries and check them against each other? Because I can query a post by it's URI like this:
query MyQuery6 {
  pageBy(uri: "about-us") {
    title
  }
}

But it won't let me query by language as well..
I would like something like this:
query MyQuery6 {
  page(where: {language: EN, uri: "about-us"}) {
    edges {
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}

Is this possible?
